# Getting e4 application model in e3 app

Tags: eclipse, rcp, e4

I'm looking at starting to use Eclipse RCP e4 facilities from within a large application based on Eclipse 3.x.  For this reason, I don't have an e4xmi file.

The application model does exist underneath the compatibility layer, but it is difficult to get hold of it from code (note that you can get everything using dependency injection, but only once you have persuaded the framework to start creating objects for you).

Here is the only way of getting the model I can find:

```
PartSite ps = (PartSite)PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
              .getActivePage().getActivePart().getSite();
IEclipseContext iec = ps.getContext();
MApplication ma = iec.get(MApplication.class);
```

Ignoring for the time being the fact that PartSite is internal API, is there an easier way to get hold of the model?  Why is it so hard to find?

Comment: It is hard to find because it is not really intended for use by a 3.x style application.

Comment: OK.  I realise what I'm doing is against the rules, but there are some articles around which talk about soft migrations.  It certainly seems that starting to use the e4 facilities from deep within a 3.x app is not a pleasant experience.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Eclipse Luna due for release this month lets you add e4 style views to 3.x style apps - http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/S-4.4M1-201308072000/news/

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want you could use this snippet.

```
    IWorkbench workbench = getService(IWorkbench.class, IWorkbench.class);
    MApplication mApplication = workbench.getApplication();
    EModelService modelService = mApplication.getContext().get(EModelService.class);
```

This is how I get the service from OSGi

```
private <T> T getService(Class<T> pClass, Class pContextClass) {
    BundleContext context = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(pContextClass).getBundleContext();
    ServiceReference<T> reference = context.getServiceReference(pClass);
    if(reference == null){
        return null;}
    T service = context.getService(reference);
    return service;
}
```

After that you could do this:

```
    MWindow window = modelService.createModelElement(MWindow.class);
    window.setHeight(100);
    window.setWidth(100);
    window.setLabel("Hello");
    window.setVisible(true);
    mApplication.getChildren().add(window);
```

Hope this helps.

Wim

Comment: It works - I get the little window - but I still get an exception org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process "WorkbenchWindow.model": no actual value was found for the argument "MTrimmedWindow".  I find it hard to understand what's going on behind the scenes, but it feels like I'm breaking some rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Trimmed Window.

```
MTrimmedWindow trimmedWindow = modelService.createModelElement(MTrimmedWindow.class);
trimmedWindow.setX(100);
trimmedWindow.setY(50);
trimmedWindow.setWidth(100);
trimmedWindow.setHeight(50);
window.setLabel("Hello");
window.setVisible(true);
mApplication.getChildren().add(window);
```

If you use `MWindow`, then you probably get an exception

**`org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process "WorkbenchWindow.model"`**

In this case, you need to use `MTrimmedWindow`.